# RequiredFieldValidator wont allow user to leave page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, validation

I have Required field validators on some of my textboxes on some pages but when the user clicks on that page and then tries to click on a different page it wont let the user leave the page until the textboxes have been filled

How do i overcome this?

Comment: Where does he try to click on a "different page"? Is that a hyperlink?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> tries to click on a different page it wont let the user leave the page

I assume `clicking on a different page` requires the page to post back to server again.

If so, set the control's [CausesValidation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.causesvalidation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)="False".

For example,

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"/>
```